# How to prove Brownian is a Martingale as to the part of measurability

Tags: brownian-motion, martingales

How can I prove in an exhaustive way that a Brownian Motion $B_t$ is a martingale with respect to its natural filtration as to the part in which one has to show that $B_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable, that is the fact that:
$$B_t^{-1}(B)\subset\mathcal{F}_t, \forall B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{R})$$
I know that $$\sigma[B_t]\subset\sigma[B_s|0\leq s\leq t]=\mathcal{F}_t$$ 
But how can this result imply the measurability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sigma(B_t)\subset\sigma(B_s:s\le t)$, for any Borel set $C$, $B_t^{-1}(C)\in \sigma(B_s:s\le t)$. Then using the Markov property, for $t>s$,
$$
\mathsf{E}[B_t\mid \mathcal{F}_s]=\mathsf{E}[B_s+(B_t-B_s)\mid \mathcal{F}_s]=B_s \quad\text{a.s.}
$$

Comment: This part is clear to me. What is not clear among the proofs of the three properties of a martingale, is the measurability part

Comment: @user600927 I see. The natural filtration here is $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(B_s:s\le t)$.

Comment: Is there any conceptual difference between the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a r.v. $X$ (i.e. $\sigma[X]$) and the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a stochastic process such as the Brownian Motion (in our case $\sigma[B_t]$)?

Comment: No. $B_t$ is a kind of an infinite dimensional "random vector".

Comment: Ok, so here comes the point I'm stucked in..a random variable is measurable by definition, so, theoretically, I would not have to prove that $B_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable.

Comment: It is measurable w.r.t. what $\sigma$-field. Compare your case to the following: consider a random vector $[X_1,X_2]^{\top}$. $X_1$ is clearly measurable w.r.t. $\sigma([X_1,X_2]^{\top})$...

Comment: In order for a stochastic process such as $(B_t)_{t\in N}$ to be measurable, does it suffice to show that$ B_t$ is measurable for some $t\in N$?

Comment: Your question is not related to the measurability of the process $(B_t)$. It is related to the measurability of $B_t$ w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}_t$. These are different concepts.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to prove.

$B_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable by definition of $\mathcal{F}_t$

$\mathcal{F}_t$ is defined as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra s.t. $B_s$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable for all $s \in [0,t]$, so especially $B_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable.